# Mysql Service doesnt show but can login and is running

Tags: mysql, centos

OK something odd and maybe im missing something simple here. I am trying to diagnose a problem I think that max connections are being reached and need to up them. Upon further looking I ran `# service --status-all` and then I noticed that mysqld was not in the list so I tried `service mysqld status` which returned `mysqld: unrecognized service` .  but if I run `mysql - p MYPASS` I am logged in to mysql and can see all my databases as normal. also I log into phpmyadmin just fine all databases are there. Also have several scripts running using 'localhost' and my mysqlusername and pass, and they are running just fine...

So I am not sure why I am not seeing the mysql service, anyone have some idea? or can point me in some direction?

I am using Centos, I did not set this machine up that person is no longer here, I have several other servers running mysql as well and I checked all those all is right.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the service has not been registered.

On a working box do;

`chkconfig --list mysqld` it should return something like;

`mysqld          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:off   6:off`

Now do the same on the box in question - if nothing comes back then you need to `chkconfig --add mysqld` then re run the above commands to verify its registered, then you should be able to access it via the service manager.